# display list of cases related to contact on service console left sidebar

Tags: dynamic-visualforce, related-list, person-accounts, custom-console-components, custom-service-console

We have email-to-case enabled and I have created a console to manage the cases and using custom console components, I am trying to display a list of cases related to a contact.

I am trying to achieve this list in the console. 
[image: Cases List in Console]
I am unfortunately unable to replicate the same list from another Org to the Org I am working on. It was developed by a different vendor and has a lot of code. Is there a method to display related cases to a contact in the service console component?

I came across a small code which displays the case list based on Contact ID. I created a VF page and had this code in it and created a custom console component and used this VF page there.

Code used:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case">
<apex:relatedList list="Cases" subject="{!Case.ContactID}"/>
</apex:page>
```

I am getting this error message in the console for the code I have used and we are currently using Person Accounts. I am Admin and cannot write code. Please help.

Error message:
[image: Error message in Side Left Bar in the Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is related to the nature of `person accounts`. A person account takes most of the information from contacts that aren't on the account object and adds it to the account detail page; duplicating it in the database. If you have account record types other than person accounts, you'll want to check the contact's record type before you attempt to display your related list.

If the *only* type of `Accounts` you use for `Cases` are `person accounts`, then what you'll want to do is change your list to the account object for that contact since each contact will only have *one* account. If that's your situation, it actually would be preferable to use the `accountId` rather than the `contactId` to track your cases. I recognize that's not the normal way cases and the console are configured to operate. Perhaps if you do some additional research on person accounts, you may find a solution for this particular issue that's out of the box since it's clearly the cause of your problem.

Comment: I tried changing the code with AccountID and it worked. I am able to see the related cases list view. I am able to view it as Sys Admin but when I am logging in as a different user, I am getting the insufficient privileges message instead of the list view. I have checked the Account and Contact Object permissions on the custom profile and both of them are having CRU privileges. Still trying to figure out how to display it for custom profile users.

Comment: This might be a good use case for [Criteria-Based Sharing Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_cbs_about.htm).

Comment: I finally was able to display the related list view for other users after adding the VF page to their profile. Yes, it is a good use case to use for standard functionality available out of box in SF.

Answer (score 1):

The console provides an out-of-box related list sidebar to help with this without needing code. It will display a related list in a sidebar of the page layout you configure it on. You can edit the Mini Page Layout to add or remove fields from the sidebar.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_console_components_lists_setup.htm